# How to use Spectral theorem in this proof?

Tags: operator-theory, operator-algebras, spectral-theory, von-neumann-algebras

In the book [Kadison-Ringrose II](https://books.google.co.in/books/about/Fundamentals_of_the_Theory_of_Operator_A.html?id=h5bMkZTnowAC&redir_esc=y) in proposition 8.5.2 (image attached below) it seems that the authors used the fact:

> *Given a non-zero positive operator $T$ in a von Neumann algebra there exists a suitable spectral projection $G$ of $T$, and some positive real number $c$ such that $cG\le T$.*

I tried to verify this statement using Spectral Theorem ([KR I](https://bookstore.ams.org/view?ProductCode=GSM/15), Theorem 5.2.2). By part (iv) of the spectral theorem we can get $c>0$ such that $c(I-E)\le T(I-E)$ for some spectral projection of $T$. But this doesn't imply the above fact.

*Question 1.* How does the above fact follow from **Theorem 5.2.2**?

*Question 2.* Is the converse of Proposition 8.5.2(i) true? What I mean is suppose $\mathcal{R}$ is a vNa and $\rho$ is a tracial weight on it such that for every non-zero $A\in \mathcal{R}^+$, there is a non-zero projection $G$ in $F_\rho$, and a positive number $a$ s.t. $A\ge aG$. Then can we say that $\rho$ is semi-finite (see definition 7.5.1)?

Thank you.

[image: Proposition 8.5.2]

Comment: I don't know what the exact statement of Theorem 5.2.2 is but this is trivial from the multiplication operator formulation of the spectral theorem (which says you can identify your Hilbert space with some $L^2$ space and $T$ by an operator given by multiplication by a function; then the statement is just that if $f$ is a nonnegative function that is not $0$ almost everywhere then there is a characteristic function $g$ of a set of positive measure and $c>0$ such that $cg\leq f$).

Comment: Thanks Eric Wofsey!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Theorem 5.2.2 in Kadison-Ringrose is not my favourite formulation of the Spectral Theorem, partly because it obscures the fact that $(-\infty,\lambda)\longmapsto E_\lambda$ induces a projection-valued measure on the Borel sets of $\mathbb R$.

Since $T$ is positive and nonzero, there exists $c>0$ such that $$[c,\|T\|]\cap\sigma(T)\ne\varnothing.$$
Let $G=E([c,\|T\|])$, that is
$$
G=\int_{\sigma(T)}1_{[c,\|T\|]}(\lambda)\,dE_\lambda.
$$
The fact that $G$ is a projection follows from typical computations in functional calculus, and
$$
cG\leq\int_{\sigma(T)\cap[c,\|T\|]}\lambda\,dE_\lambda\leq\int_{\sigma(T)}\lambda\,dE_\lambda=T. 
$$

The above said, the theorem does give you the inequality directly. As you say,
$$
c(I-E_c)\leq T(I-E_c). 
$$
Another fact that is obscured by the statement of the theorem (though it follows straighforwardly from it) is that $TE_\lambda=E_\lambda T$ for all $\lambda  $ (in fact, $E_\lambda$ belongs to the von Neumann algebra generated by $T$). Then
$$
T(I-E_c)=T^{1/2}(I-E_c)T^{1/2}\leq T^{1/2}IT^{1/2}=T. 
$$

---

As for 8.5.2.(i), the converse is true, see [this question and answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1839114/semi-finite-trace-on-a-von-neumann-algebra-equivalent-definitions). Note that this only makes sense if the weight is faithful. If $\rho(A)=0$, no  nonzero $G\in F_\rho$ as in the statement can exist.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I understood question 1. But regarding the weight you constructed in question 2, what are $A_t$ in the definition of $\rho$? I assumed it’s the scalar $a_t$ satisfying $AE_t=a_tE_t$. Right?

Comment: Yes, $A$ is a function $A:[0,1]\to\mathbb C$. The notation $A_t$ is the same that is used for sequences.

Comment: Also regarding *question 2*, here (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1839114/semi-finite-trace-on-a-von-neumann-algebra-equivalent-definitions) "$1\iff 4$" implies that the converse of question 2 is true. Isn't it? I mean being a *-subalgebra $\mathcal{M}_\rho$ would be  WOT dense iff $4$ satisfies.

Comment: Yes, you are right. And if you look carefully you'll notice that said answer from 6 years ago is mine... Shame on me. I'll edit the answer soon.

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: Glad I could help! I love this stuff.